# How to calculate difference of lowest date and highest date among array of sub documents?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, datetime, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following sub-documents:

```
experiences: [
{
    "workExperienceId" : ObjectId("59f8064e68d1f61441bec94a"),
    "workType" : "Full Time",
    "functionalArea" : "Law",
    "company" : "Company A",
    "title" : "new",
    "from" : ISODate("2010-10-13T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "to" : ISODate("2012-10-13T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f8064e68d1f61441bec94b"),
    "currentlyWorking" : false
},
...
...
{
    "workExperienceId" : ObjectId("59f8064e68d1f61441bec94a"),
    "workType" : "Full Time",
    "functionalArea" : "Law",
    "company" : "Company A",
    "title" : "new",
    "from" : ISODate("2014-10-14T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "to" : ISODate("2015-12-13T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f8064e68d1f61441bec94c"),
    "currentlyWorking" : false
},
{
    "workExperienceId" : ObjectId("59f8064e68d1f61441bec94a"),
    "workType" : "Full Time",
    "functionalArea" : "Law",
    "company" : "Company A",
    "title" : "new",
    "from" : ISODate("2017-10-13T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "to" : null,
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f8064e68d1f61441bec94d"),
    "currentlyWorking" : true
},
{
    "workExperienceId" : ObjectId("59f8064e68d1f61441bec94a"),
    "workType" : "Full Time",
    "functionalArea" : "Law",
    "company" : "Company A",
    "title" : "new",
    "from" : ISODate("2008-10-14T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "to" : ISODate("2009-12-13T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f8064e68d1f61441bec94c"),
    "currentlyWorking" : false
},
]
```

As you see, there may not be date ordered within sequential date and maybe a non ordered date. Above data is for each user. So what I want is to get total years of experience for each user in year format. When `to` field is null and `currentlyWorking` is true then it means that I am currently working on that company.

Answer (score 3):

## Aggregation

Using the aggregation framework you could apply [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) where you have it available:

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "difference": {
      "$subtract": [
        { "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [{ "$indexOfArray": ["$experiences.to", null] }, -1] },
            { "$max": "$experiences.to" },
            new Date()
        ]},
        { "$min": "$experiences.from" }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Failing that as long as the "latest" is always the last in the array, using [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/):

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "difference": {
      "$subtract": [
        { "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$experiences.to", -1] }, null] },
            new Date(),
            { "$max": "$experiences.to" }
        ]},
        { "$min": "$experiences.from" }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

That's pretty much the most efficient ways to do this, as a single pipeline stage applying [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) and [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operators. For [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) you would need MongoDB 3.4 at least, and for simply using [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) you can have MongoDB 3.2, which is the minimal version you should be running in production environments anyway.

One pass, means it gets done fast with little overhead.

The brief parts are the [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) and [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) allow you to extract the appropriate values directly from the array elements, being the "smallest" value of `"from"` and the largest value of `"to"` within the array. Where available the [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) operator can return the matched index from a provided array ( in this case from `"to"` values ) where a specified value ( as `null` here ) exists. If it's there the index of that value is returned, and where it is not the value of `-1` is returned indicating that it is not found.

We use [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) which is a "ternary" or `if..then..else` operator to determine that when the `null` is not found `then` you want the [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) value from `"to"`. Of course when it is found this is the `else` where the value of the current `Date` which is fed into the aggregation pipeline as an external parameter on execution is returned instead.

The alternate case for a MongoDB 3.2 is that you instead "presume" the last element of your array is the most recent employment history item. In generally would be best practice to order these items so the most recent was either the "last" ( as seems to be indicated in your question ) or the "first" entry of the array. It would be logical to keep these entries in such order as opposed to relying on sorting the list at runtime.

So when using a "known" position such as "last", we can use the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operator to return the value from the array at the specified position. Here it is `-1` for the "last" element. The "first" element would be `0`, and could arguably be applied to geting the "smallest" value of `"from"` as well, since you should have your array in order. Again [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) is used to transpose the values depending on whether `null` is returned. As an alternate to [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) you can even use [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) to swap the values instead:

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "difference": {
      "$subtract": [
        { "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$experiences.to", -1] }, new Date()] },
        { "$min": "$experiences.from" }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

That operator essentially switches out the values returned if the response of the first condition is `null`. So since we are grabbing the value from the "last" element already, we can "presume" that this does mean the "largest" value of `"to"`.

The [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) is what actually returns the "difference", since when you "subtract" one date from another the difference is returned as the milliseconds value between the two. This is how BSON Dates are actually internally stored, and it's the common internal date storage of date formats being the "milliseconds since epoch".

If you want the interval in a specific duration such as "years", then it's a simple matter of applying the "date math" to change from the **milliseconds** difference between the date values. So adjust by dividing out from the interval ( also showing [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) on the `"from"` just for completeness ):

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "difference": {
      "$floor": {
        "$divide": [
          { "$subtract": [
            { "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$experiences.to", -1] }, new Date()] },
            { "$arrayElemAt": ["$experiences.from", 0] }
          ]},
          1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

That uses [`$divide`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/) as a math operator and `1000` milliseconds `60` for each of seconds and minutes, `24` hours and `365` days as the divisor value. The [`$floor`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/floor/) "rounds down" the number from decimal places. You can do whatever you want there, but it "should" be used "inline" and not in separate stages, which simply add to processing overhead.

Of course, the presumption of `365` days is an "approximation" at best. If you want something more complete, then you can instead apply the [date aggregation operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) to the values to get a more accurate reading. So here, also applying [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) to declare as "variables" for later manipulation:

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "difference": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "to": { "$ifNull": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$experiences.to", -1] }, new Date()] },
          "from": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$experiences.from", 0] }
        },
        "in": {
          "years": { 
            "$subtract": [
              { "$subtract": [
                { "$year": "$$to" }, 
                { "$year": "$$from" }
              ]},
              { "$cond": {
                "if": { "$gt": [{ "$month": "$$to" },{ "$month": "$$from" }] },
                "then": 0,
                "else": 1
              }}
            ]
          },
          "months": {
            "$add": [
              { "$subtract": [
                { "$month": "$$to" },
                { "$month": "$$from" }
              ]},
              { "$cond": {
                "if": { "$gt": [{ "$month": "$$to" },{ "$month": "$$from" }] },
                "then": 0,
                "else": 12
              }}
            ]
          },
          "days": {
            "$add": [
              { "$subtract": [
                { "$dayOfYear": "$$to" },
                { "$dayOfYear": "$$from" }
              ]},
              { "$cond": {
                "if": { "$gt": [{ "$month": "$$to" },{ "$month": "$$from" }] },
                "then": 0,
                "else": 365
              }}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Again that's a slight approximation on the days of the year. MongoDB 3.6 actually would allow you to test the "leap year" by implementing [`$dateFromParts`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/) to determine if 29th February was valid in the current year or not by assembling from the "pieces" we have available.

---

## Work with returned data

Of course all the above is using the aggregation framework to determine the intervals from the array for each person. This would be the advised course if you were intending to "reduce" the data returned by essentially not returning the array items at all, or if you wanted these numbers for further aggregation in reporting to a larger "sum" or "average" statistic from the data.

If on the other hand you actually do want all the data returned for the person including the complete "experiences" array, then it's probably the best course of action to simply apply the calculations "after" all the data is returned from the server as you process each item returned.

The simple application of this would be to "merge" a new field into the results, just like [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) does but on the "client" side instead:

```
Model.find().lean().cursor().map( doc => 
  Object.assign(doc, {
    "difference": 
      ((doc.experiences.map(e => e.to).indexOf(null) === -1)
        ? Math.max.apply(null, doc.experiences.map(e => e.to))
        : new Date() )
      - Math.min.apply(null, doc.experiences.map(e => e.from)
  })
).toArray((err, result) => {
   // do something with result
})
```

That's just applying the same logic represented in the first aggregation example to a "client" side processing of the result cursor. Since you are using mongoose, the [`.cursor()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-cursor) method actually returns us a [`Cursor`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html) object from the underlying driver, of which mongoose normally hides away for "convenience". Here we want it because it gives us access to some handy methods.

The [`Cursor.map()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#map) is one such handy method which allows use to apply a "transform" on the content returned from the server. Here we use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to "merge" a new property to the returned document. We could alternately use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the "array" returned by mongoose by "default", but processing inline looks a little cleaner, as well as being a bit more efficient.

In fact [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is the main tool here in manipulation since where we applied statements like `"$experiences.to"` in the aggregation statement, we apply on the "client" using `doc.experiences.map(e => e.to)`, which does the same thing "transforming" the array of objects into an "array of values" for the specified field instead.

This allows the same checking using [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) against the array of values, and also the [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) are used in the same way, implementing [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to use those "mapped" array values as the argument values to the functions.

Finally of course since we still have a [`Cursor`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html) being returned, we convert this back into the more typical form you would work with mongoose results as an "array" using [`Cursor.toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#toArray), which is exactly what mongoose does "under the hood" for you on it's default requests.

The [`Query.lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) us a mongoose modifier which basically says to return and expect "plain JavaScript Objects" as opposed to "mongoose documents" matched to the schema with applied methods that are again the default return. We want that because we are "manipulating" the result. Again the alternate is to do the manipulation "after" the default array is returned, and convert via `.toObject()` which is present on all mongoose documents, in the event that "serializing virtual properties" is important to you.

So this is essentially a "mirror" of that first aggregation approach, yet applied to "client side" logic instead. As stated, it generally makes more sense to do it this way when you actually want ALL of the properties in the document in results anyway. The simple reason being that it makes no real since to add "additional" data to the results returned "before" you return those from the server. So instead, simply apply the transform "after" the database returns them.

Also much like above, the same client transformation approaches can be applied as was demonstrated in ALL the aggregation examples. You can even employ external libraries for date manipulation which give you "helpers" for some of the "raw math" approaches here.

Comment: Confused, your query return different result from @Felix query. Now don't know which one return the right result.

Comment: @NimatullahRazmjo Had no idea anyone else had answered. What are you trying to get the difference of? I'm giving you the difference from the array "within each document". So what are you actually looking for? I presumed this was the "work experience" for a person. Therefore looking at "from" and "to" outside the scope of a "person" ( which would be one document ) would not seem to make any sense.

Comment: Want to know total years of experience of user.

Comment: @NimatullahRazmjo Sure, so a "user" is **one document** right? And the "array" here represents all their listed "experience" or "jobs" with start to finish. That's what I'm giving you, being the difference between the `$min` from date in the array to the `$max` to date in the array, or of course where you have a `null` to be "todays date now". The interval returned is milliseconds between the dates. But getting to years is basic date math. So It's what you asked for. Looking at the other answer, there is no need for all those other stages. And `$unwind` makes it just dead slow.

Comment: @NimatullahRazmjo You still appear confused on the differences ( and frankly I needed sleep ) but the short case is `$unwind` is an **old** approach for dealing with array values which is not really efficient for the purpose you outlined in your question. So whilst you "can" use that approach, it does come at a significant cost that can be avoided by extracting the values from the array in a more efficient manner. Added a full outline of the approaches to this and why you use them this way.

Comment: Thanks! You explained it more than an answer, it has a loft of thing for me to learn from your answer. Again thanks a lot.

Comment: But i have a problem in query that calculate diff by year, when i run that it shows an error: `Failed to execute script.

Error:
Assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Expression $subtract takes exactly 2 arguments. 3 were passed in.",
 "code" : 16020,
 "codeName" : "Location16020"
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1215:5
@(shell):1:1
`

Comment: @NimatullahRazmjo Ooops. Thanks, missed that. Not really an issue, as all that really need be done is to wrap the statements chaining one to the other. Give me a few minutes to adjust.

Comment: Still it has problem, when i run it shows `InternalError: too much recursion`

Comment: @NimatullahRazmjo That error has nothing to do with the aggregation pipeline. Sounds like you are looping async calls in other code. The code I gave you works just fine. I corrected the oversight with `$subtract` and have run everything against your data sample in the question to ensure it returns as expected.

Comment: When i run this on robomongo it shows `Failed to execute script.

Error:
Assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "can't convert from BSON type missing to Date",
 "code" : 16006,
 "codeName" : "Location16006"
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1215:5
@(shell):1:1`

Comment: @NimatullahRazmjo To restate, these errors have nothing to do with the code here or the data provided in the question. You already posted one error that had nothing to do with the code here, so you need to stop posting errors like this. Run the queries in the answer against the sample data you asked about here **only**. When it validates, realize your question was answered and move on please. I will say that this new error relates to "missing data", meaning there is likely a missing `from` field without an `$ifNull` check or an `experiences` array even completely missing in your document,

Comment: @NimatullahRazmjo So I'm also going here with the general advice that answers are provided "within the scope of the question you ask and data you provide **only**". The give/retract/accept/decline voting behavior of "holding someone to ransom unless they answer all your followup questions" is bad behavior here. The errors you have posted here should have been addressed by [Asking a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) .

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with the aggregation framework like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $unwind:"$experiences"
   },
   {
      $sort:{
         "experiences.from":1
      }
   },
   {
      $group:{
         _id:null,
         "from":{
            $first:"$experiences.from"
         },
         "to":{
            $last:{
               $ifNull:[
                  "$to",
                  new Date()
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $project:{
         "diff":{
            $subtract:[
               "$to",
               "$from"
            ]
         }
      }
   }
])
```

This returns:

```
{ "_id" : null, "diff" : NumberLong("65357827142") }
```

Which is the difference in **ms** between the two dates, see [$subtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) for details

You can get the **year** by adding this additional stage to the end of the pipeline:

```
{
   $project:{
      "year":{
         $floor:{
            $divide:[
               "$diff",
               1000*60*60*24*365
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This would then return:

```
{ "_id" : null, "year" : 2 }
```

Comment: How we can calculate its difference in year or month, is there any function like mysql `YEAR`, `MONTH` or we should calculate it itself.

Comment: This is possible with some other aggregation stages, but it would be way easier to do this directly in javascript with a library like [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: But i need this in query, because i have a year value and want to compare this difference with that year value.

Comment: Thanks It seems ok, let me check it. But to be more clear for u, I want to know total years of experience of each user.

Comment: Your answer return difference for only one user.

Comment: @NimatullahRazmjo Well there is no `user_id` or anything similar in the samples you provided... To get results for each users, group by `user_id` in the **`$group`** stage